# how can i place a specific row(based on column value) always at bottom of table with ng-table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable, angularjs-ng-table

I am new to `AngularJs` and `ng-table`, I tried to sort the `ng-table` with the sortable attribute its working fine but I had a  row with the final result, here how can I use sortable with out impact on a specific row?

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" ng-model="Controller.data" class="table" show-filter="true">
   <tr ng-if="entry.task_name!='Totals'" ng-class="{info: $even, active: $odd}" ng-repeat="entry in $data">
     <td  data-title="'Task Name'" sortable="'taskName'" filter="{ 'taskName': 'text' }"><div ng-show="entry.taskName!=false">{{entry.taskName}}</div></td>
     <td  data-title="'Planned Hours'" sortable="'plannedHours'">{{entry.plannedHours}}</td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-if="entry.task_name ==='Totals'" ng-class="{info: $even, active: $odd}" ng-repeat="entry in $data">
     <td  data-title="'Task Name'" >{{entry.taskName}}</td>
     <td  data-title="'Planned Hours'">{{entry.plannedHours}}</td>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td ng-show="repCtrl.noData" ng-bind="repCtrl.noData"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to put this row in `<tfoot>?`

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" ng-model="Controller.data" class="table" show-filter="true">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-class="{info: $even, active: $odd}" ng-repeat="entry in $data | filter: myFilter">
      <td data-title="'Task Name'" sortable="'taskName'" filter="{ 'taskName': 'text' }">
        <div ng-show="entry.taskName!=false">{{entry.taskName}}</div>
      </td>
      <td data-title="'Planned Hours'" sortable="'plannedHours'">{{entry.plannedHours}}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ng-show="repCtrl.noData" ng-bind="repCtrl.noData"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr ng-repeat="entry in $data | filter: {taskName:'Totals'}">
      <td>{{entry.taskName}}</td>
      <td>{{entry.plannedHours}}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<script>
   $scope.myFilter = function (item) { 
        return item.taskName !== 'Totals'; 
    };
</script>
```

my plnkr with different data, but working as you expected: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rx7Kqp?p=preview